# How to populate an array within an array in MATLAB and how to access them?

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array

For example

```
A = {{1,2},{23,34},{45,4},...}
```

How to create such a data type in MATLAB

How to access the `i`-th element and the elements within it?

For Ex. `A[2]` should return `{23,34}` and `A[2].1` should return `23`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
A = {{1,2},{23,34},{45,4},...}
```

is valid MATLAB syntax, if you are trying to make a cell array of cell arrays. However, you'd probably want to store vectors rather than arrays in your array:

```
A = {[1,2],[23,34],[45,4],...}
```

Access them like `A{2}` or `A(2)` but far more likely the first one. If you want an individual element then `A{2}(1)`

But if every one of your cells is going to contain a 2 element vector then you will have a much easier time just using a 2D matrix:

```
A = [1,2;23,34;45,4;,...]
```

And and now access the entire row i.e. `A(2,:)` or for an individual element `A(2,1)`

Comment: Additional Information. I was trying to populate data of coordinate points obtained from an image for further calculations. Ex. of .m (matlab file) for the above question will look like...  `for c = 1:max_c   for r = 1:max_r   // Any condition you maybe want to check   A(count,:) = [c,r] //   count = count+1   end   end`